# How to use go to verify whether the plaintext password is the same as the salt md5 password?

Tags: python, go

Python:

```
# generate password
ldap_salted_md5.hash("123456") 
# verify password
ldap_salted_md5.verify("123456","{SMD5}991RjK3DQCT+ri/yxQB613Yuxdg=")
# return true
```

shell:

```
# generate password
slappasswd -h {SMD5} -s "123456" 
# return {SMD5}ZmDHoIiZZG/weuCNkLj189sFoPM=
# verify password by python 
ldap_salted_md5.verify("123456","{SMD5}ZmDHoIiZZG/weuCNkLj189sFoPM=")
# return True
```

I want to use go to implement this step of ldap_salted_md5.verify

Comment: Please share your go code and tell us what is not working on it, then maybe someone can help you. In any case if you don't know how to code, just make a search on google and you will find many examples of `go encode decode md5 salt`, as for example this one https://github.com/anaskhan96/go-password-encoder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```golang
        saltPassword := strings.Replace(user.Password, "{SMD5}", "", -1)
        decodeSaltPassword, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(saltPassword)
        checksum := decodeSaltPassword[0:16]
        salt := decodeSaltPassword[16:]

        md5Ctx := md5.New()
        md5Ctx.Write([]byte(bindSimplePw))
        md5Ctx.Write(salt)
        cipherStr := md5Ctx.Sum(nil)

        if !bytes.Equal(checksum, cipherStr) {

            return ldap.LDAPResultInvalidCredentials, nil
        }
```